# Angular exposes login and password in browser address bar

Tags: angular, authentication, ng-idle

I have an Angular 9 application. Sometimes (very rare) I face a problem when my auth data is exposed right in the browser address bar
E.g. instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/#/application/48
```

it for some reason looks like

```
http://localhost:8080/?username=foo&password=bar#/application/48
```

It happence not very oftern but anyway. I use an `ng-idle` library in my app. It makes the application to returns back to login page after some idle timeout. And according to my observations the problem occurrs after the ng-idle job is done.

What is the problem? Is there any way to strictly prohibit the exposing?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a login form that is being submitted with the username and password, This is the default behaviour of `form`, Here is how you can stop the submission of form and manually submit the form to API.

```
//HTML
<form (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
 <input type="text" name="username">
 <input type="password" name="password">
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>

//TS
onSubmit(evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();//Stops submitting form
 //Call API to login
}
```

Comment: I have chek it out. Nothing changed.